# Arabic in Chtml::label Yii

Tags: yii, arabic-support

I've got a problem with arabic and some other languages like greek when I'm trying to show text with Chtml::label with Yii and user access to website without log in.
Everything is ok when the user is logged in and the curious thing is that the form is exactly the same. 
If got charset ok in the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

That's an example of how I see the text in arabic:

ل� يش�ل التقرير كل �ا كنت أنتظره

And that's the same text in the same form when the user is logged in:

لم يشمل التقرير كل ما كنت أنتظره

Code in yii to retrieve the data:

```
<div class="section row principal_question">
        <?php echo CHtml::label($textt, null, array('class'=>'question_nps')); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test with below code somewhere in your code and update your label text with Yii::t return text.

```
Yii::app()->language = 'ar';
echo Yii::t('TransalorTest', 'لم يشمل التقرير كل ما كنت أنتظره');
Yii::app()->end();
```

I hope, this will help you.

Comment: Hi!!! It works!!! Except if I remove Yii::app()->end(); Then, the result is wrong. Any option without Yii::app()->end(); ?